# Assigning seats to 6 girls and 4 boys

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have this problem for Morin's Probability for the Enthusiastic Beginnner. Question 1.1.

> Six girls and four boys are to be assigned to ten seats in a row, with stipulations that a girl sits in the third seat and a boy sits in the eighth seat. How many arrangements are possible?

There are six possibilities for the 6 girls in the third seat and four possibilities for the four boys in the eighth seat. So I started with $6 \times 4$

Then for the remaining eight seats we don't care whether it's a boy or a girl, so we can join hte rest of the boys and girls into one group to select from and make $N = 8$ and use $N! = 8!$

So the answer I got is $$6 \times 4 \times 8!$$

Have I done this right?
Thanks.

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: ok thanks @insipidintegrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea that should be right.

Since each boy and girl is distinguishable, we have

._ _ G _ _ _ _ B _ _.

For this initial arrangement, there are $\ ^6C_1=6$ ways to choose the girl, and $\ ^4C_1=4$ ways to choose the boy. We can then completely ignore these two and focus on the other $8$ slots. Since they are distinguishable, order matters when we distribute the slots, so we have $\ ^8P_8=8!$ ways to do this.

Hence as you've calculated the answer is just $24\cdot 8!=967680$.

Comment: thanks @Max0815